# React dynamic import based on the prop from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible I can dynamic import based on the props from Parent in React?

For my code:

### Parent

```
<Parent>
 <Child icon="svg1" />
 <Child icon="svg2" />
 <Child icon="svg3" />
</Parent>
```

### Child

```
import svg1 from './svg1.js'
import svg2 from './svg2.js'
import svg3 from './svg3.js'
```

```
switch (props.icon)
{
 case 'svg1':
   output = <svg1/>
   break
 case 'svg2':
   ouput = <svg2/>
   break
 default:
   ouput = <svg3/>
}
```

```
return (
 <div>
  {output}
 </div>
)
```

How can I use a dynamic icon value to import svg element based on the icon value from parent rather than swtich?

Comment: I don't understand, the parent props is a string or something else ?

Comment: It's a string and the value is the name of svg icon element. I wrap svg icons to React element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid doing a switch, you could build an object with your imports:

```
const icons = {
  svg1,
  svg2,
  svg3,
};

const Child = (props) => {
  const Component = icons[props.icon];
  return <Component />;
};
```

Comment: Is it possible I can use props.icon only on child rather than the svg1, svg2 or svg3? If I have more icons then, I will add manully to icons object, it is not a totally dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the image tag, like this;

```
import svg1 from './svg1.js'
import svg2 from './svg2.js'
import svg3 from './svg3.js'


<Parent>
 <Child icon={svg1} />
 <Child icon={svg2} />
 <Child icon={svg3} />
</Parent>
```

Child

```
return (
 <div>
  <img src={output} />
 </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this one - https://sung.codes/blog/2017/12/03/loading-react-components-dynamically-demand/

I finally get the solution:

```
const { icon } = props
const [components, setComponents] = useState([])

const addComponent = async (icon) => {
    import(`./${icon}.js`)
        .then((component) => {
            setComponents(components.concat(component.default))
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(`"${icon}" not yet supported`)
        })
}

const getElement = async (icon) => {
    await addComponent(icon)
}

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("icon", icon)
    getElement(icon)
}, [])

const componentsElements = components.map((Component) => <Component />)
...
return <div>{componentsElements}</div>
```